# remove last character from xml element data

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a xml node as below

```
<root>
    <element>ABC,EFG, XYZ,<element>
</root>
```

I want to remove last ',' from . 
And result should be ABC,EFG, XYZ
I want to use XSL 1.0 thats kind of limitation.

XSL I am trying to use

```
 <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="smallcase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" />

    <xsl:for-each select="//element">
        <xsl:if test="contains(substring(., string-length(.) - 1),$smallcase)">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 1, string-length(.) - 1)"/>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(., string-length(.) - 1)"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 9):

You can do this with a combination of `substring` and `string-length`:

```
substring(., 1, string-length(.) - 1)
```

I'm not sure what your current XSLT is trying to do - it will simply print the last two characters of each `element` element - but try something like this instead:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="//element"/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- match elements whose content ends with a comma, and strip it off -->
<xsl:template match="element[substring(., string-length()) = ',']">
  <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 1, string-length(.) - 1)" />
</xsl:template>
```

Other `element` elements (ones that don't end with a comma) will be handled by the [default template rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule) which will just print out all their text content in full.

Comment: In doing so If my last character is not ',', I would loose that as well.

Comment: @user3138596 then you'd have to check that condition first, either with an `if` or `choose` or as a predicate on the template match pattern. If you edit your question to show the XSLT you've tried so far then I'd be able to indicate how best to slot this in.

Answer (score 0):

Using this input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <element>ABC,EFG, XYZ,</element>
    <element>ABC,EFG, XYZ</element>
</root>
```

and this stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

   <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="root/element">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:call-template name="tokenizeString">
                    <xsl:with-param name="list" select="."/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="','"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="tokenizeString">
        <!--passed template parameter -->
        <xsl:param name="list"/>
        <xsl:param name="delimiter"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($list, $delimiter) and substring-after($list,$delimiter) != ''">
                <!-- get everything in front of the first delimiter -->
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($list,$delimiter)"/>
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                <xsl:call-template name="tokenizeString">
                    <!-- store anything left in another variable -->
                    <xsl:with-param name="list" select="normalize-space(substring-after($list,$delimiter))"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="delimiter" select="$delimiter"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$list = ''"/>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:value-of select="translate($list, ',', '')"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the output is as follows:

```
<element>ABC,EFG,XYZ</element>
<element>ABC,EFG,XYZ</element>
```